# Postgres error [42883] and [42601] while executing stored procedure from trigger

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger which will execute a stores procedure which will update few rows. Procedure works when I test it using **Call** method  but the  trigger can not find it with error that function does not exists. 
Here is my procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE update_reg_location(latitude text, longitude text,userid int)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
update users set reg_lat=latitude , reg_lon=longitude where id =userid
$$;
```

When I use

```
call update_reg_location('123','234',1)
```

from IDE its works fine and record is updated but when i use it in trigger it wont compile.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_reg_location
    after INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_reg_location('123','234',1);
```

Also getting error when I want to get new value of the inserted row like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_reg_location
    after INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_reg_location(new.lat,new.lon,1);
```

getting error as **syntax error at or near new.** (new.lat,new.lon,1); in this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass parameters to the procedure and you don't need to use `UPDATE` if you use a BEFORE trigger, you can simply assign the values.

Trigger functions also need to use PL/pgSQL, you can't write them in SQL.

```
create or replace function update_reg_location()
  returns trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
  new.reg_lat = new.lat;
  new.reg_lon = new.lon;
  return new;
end;
$$;
```

Then define a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_reg_location
    BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_reg_location();
```

Comment: Getting a new error.
SQL error[42P13] Function result type must be specified